# C# interface or abstract class that accepts parameter of its own field

Tags: c#, .net, interface, abstract-class

I am trying to create an interface or an abstract class that would serve as a base for many Authorization objects.

My idea is as follows (code that does not compile but I'd like to work):

```
public abstract class AuthObject {
  public Enum Values;
  public abstract AuthObject AddPermission(Values permission);
}
```

An implementation the would look like this:

```
public class AuditLogManagement : AuthObject {
  private long _permissions;

  public new enum Values {
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Search = 2,
    Filter = 4,
    Export = 8
  }

  public AuthObject AddPermission(AuditLogManagement.Values permission) {
    _permissions |= (long)permission;
    return this;
  }
}
```

The main point of my question is how to limit parameter to AddPermission() to only this object Values field (Enum) in an interface or abstract class. However I cannot find a way to do it.

Thank You for any ideas.

Edit:

A little more simplified use case to explain the requirements:

```
interface I {
  AddPermission(I.Values permission);
}

class A : I {
  private long _permissions;

  public enum Values {
    A_a, A_b, A_c
  }
  AddPermission (this.Values newPermission) {
    _permissions |= newPermission;
  }
}

class B : I {
  private long _permissions;

  public enum Values {
    B_a, B_b, B_c
  }
  AddPermission (this.Values newPermission) {
    _permissions |= newPermission;
  }
}

var classA = new A();
var classB = new B();
A.AddPermission(A.Values.A_a); // Allowed
A.AddPermission(B.Values.B_c); // Forbidden! B_c value equals to A_c but is not the same permission!
```

Comment: How does the first code block not compile? It works for me (if I replace `Values` with `string`).

Comment: Which purpose does the base class `AuthObject` serve?

Comment: That is the point of the question.
The interface or abstract class must enforce methods of the inherited/implemented class to only accept its own enum.

Imagine 2nd method called UserManagement implementing the same interface/abstract class. It must be forbidden to do var um = new UserManagement().AddPermission(AuditLogManagement.Values.Read);
Passing an AuditLogManagement Enum values to UserManagement class object is violation of security rules. I'd like to enforce the rules using an interface or abstract class.

Comment: The AuthObject is an abstract. Each implementation can (and probably will) contain different set of Enum values in the Values field. E.g. AuditLogManagement can have Read, Export, etc. but UserManagement object may have CreateUser, UpdateUser, DeleteUser enum values. While the underlying int valuetypes may be equal (AuditLogManagement.Read = 1 == UserManagement.CreateUser = 1) it is a flaw to allow to pass AuditLogManagement.Read as parameter to UserManagment.AddPermission().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reach for generics:

```
public abstract class AuthObject<T>
     where T : struct, IConvertible // A reasonable way to constrain to an enumeration. 
                                    // you can also use System.Enum for newer versions of C# past 7.3 I believe. 
{
    public T Values { get; } 
    public abstract AuthObject<T> AddPermission(T permission);
}

public enum Values
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Search = 2,
    Filter = 4,
    Export = 8
}

public class AuditLogManagement : AuthObject<Values>
{
    private long _permissions;
    public AuthObject AddPermission(Values permission)
    {
        _permissions |= (long)permissions;
        return this;
    }
}
```

The only other suggestion I would give on top of this is to name the 'T' parameter above to something a little more descriptive, like 'TPermission' since you aren't using it for the typical container class.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three typos.<sup>1</sup>

---

```
public abstract class AuthObject {
  public Enum Values;
  public abstract AuthObject AddPermission(Values permission);
}
```

`Values` here is defined *within* the `AuditLogManagement` class. Whenever you want to use that data type outside of `AuditLogManagement`, it needs to be `AuditLogManagement.Values`.

This is the correct code:

```
public abstract class AuthObject {
  public Enum Values;
  public abstract AuthObject AddPermission(AuditLogManagement.Values permission);
}
```

---

The `AddPermission` method in your management class does not override the abstract base method.

Correct code:

```
public override AuthObject AddPermission(AuditLogManagement.Values permission)
```

(Side note: the `AuditLogManagement.` here is not necessary).

---

You've misspelled the variable (no "s" at the end):

```
_permissions |= (long)permission;
```

<sup>1: If someone does want to close the question as a typo just let me know</sup>

Comment: That is exactly what I don't need. By specifying AuditLogManagement.Values inside the abstract class or an interface you are limiting paramter to only that enum in all implementations.
The requirement states that the method must accept it's own parent class Value type.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use generics?

```
public abstract class AuthObject<T>
{
    public abstract AuthObject<T> AddPermission(T permission);
}

public class AuditLogManagement : AuthObject<Values>
{
    private Values _permissions;

    public override AuthObject<Values> AddPermission(Values permission)
    {
        _permissions |= permission;
        return this;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum Values
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Search = 2,
    Filter = 4,
    Export = 8
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You aren't declaring enum type correctly.

```
public enum Values {
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Search = 2,
    Filter = 4,
    Export = 8
}

public abstract class AuthObject {
  public Values Value;
  public abstract AuthObject AddPermission(Values permission);
}

public class AuditLogManagement : AuthObject {
  private long _permissions;
  private Values _values;

  public override AuthObject AddPermission(Values permission) {
    _permissions |= (long)permission;
    return this;
  }
}
```